# Comparing categorical outcome variables in repeated measures design

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, missing-data, proportion

I am working on an observational prospective longitudinal study with a repeated measures design. The same categorical outcome is measured for five times, for all the participants, over a time period. So there are five outcome (dependent) variables and a few predictor variables. First of all, I would like to compare the proportion of a value in the first outcome variable, compared to its proportion in every of the other four outcome variables, and find out if it's significantly smaller as assumed.

I have a few questions:

1)  Can I use a statistical analysis on two outcome variables, without including  predictor variables?

2)  What statistical analysis should I use?

3)  For some of the participants there are missing values in one or more of the five outcome variables. How should I deal with it in my analysis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'd want to use a generalized estimating equations (GEE) or mixed model for this analysis where the participant is a random effect.  You'd use a contrasts to determine if the first measurements is different from the average of the other four.  You could even try a Markov Chain Monte Carlo approach too.

To deal with missing data, I'd recommend using multiple imputation.

Comment: But GEE does rather was generally with missing data, assuming you have a relatively large number of participants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! More specifically, I am looking for risk factors for the outcome, expressed by Odds Ratios. But In some other post I have read, that GEE estimates of associations are notoriously inefficient. Is GEE an appropriate method in my case?

Comment: Before evaluating all of the predictors, I just want to find the OR for the outcome in every of the 2nd to 5th time points, compared to the first time point (as a predictor), and not the average of the other four. How can I do that?
It seems that in GEE the exposure should always be at the same person-time point as the outcome. It also seems that GEE doesn't evaluate time points separately.

Comment: GEE should be fine for what you describe above.  You'll handle the tests using a contrast.  A good introductory text to help guide your analysis can be foundin Chapter 25 of Applied Regression Analysis and Other Multivariable Methods by Kleinbaum, et al.  http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Regression-Analysis-Multivariable-Methods/dp/1285051084/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8.  In this chapter this are some good examples that show constrasts to estimates different times points like you are trying to do using GEE (aka the marginal model).